# Different behavior of class members in javascript and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript is a superset of Javascript that means Javascript code must work in Typescript.
But while I am trying to create class members in typescript file using javscript's way,
I'm getting a type error.

CODE :- script.ts (typescript file)

```
class App{
  constructor(){
        this.name = 'john';
      }     
}
    
let obj = new App();
console.log(obj.name);
    
Output : Property 'name' does not exist on type 'App'
```

But this same code works in javascript file.
Why is it not working in typescript file??

Comment: Typescript exists mainly to save you from silly things like this: instead of defining a static propery `name` you dynamically create one during construction. The type checker in Typescript doesn't know about that and therefore can't let you access it. Also: if all valid JavaScript code was also valid Typescript code, then you could never get a type check error from TS, removing the primary incentive to using it.

Comment: For the reason it tells you: _"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'App'"_. I'd suggest reading e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html.

Comment: You need a `name: string;` above the constructor. All javascript is not valid typescript. Not sure why it keeps being repeated

Comment: @adiga: probably because many places (including the Wikipedia page) say things like "[TypeScript] is a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript" and people interpret that to mean more than it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

While every JavaScript program is a *syntactically* valid TypeScript program, that doesn't mean it will have to typecheck. In your case, you'll want to add the property type declaration:

```
class App {
    name: string;
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'john';
    }     
}
    
let obj = new App();
console.log(obj.name);
```

This works as desired and [compiles to just the original JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO9oG8BQ0PQHZgLYFMAuaCAFwCcBLLAcwG51NgB7LM8gV2FOfIAoAlCkaZMpABaUIAOhwFoAXmgByAFbNxWZQ1EBfUdFS7UqEPlLRmAI1WLs+AO5xEghizbMz0kMxp9rqrJ4+AJ0QA).